Show identification: Villains turn creatures into super powered monsters
It could be an anime or a cartoon that's similar, but there were three villains similar to Jessie, James and Meowth from Pokémon. They would take creatures and turn them into crazy monsters which the hero would defeat.
I remember in one episode which could have been the finale, the pet (what could be a cat) gets turned into a monster.
This was on a disc rented from the library in the 2000's or early 2010's

Have you tried contacting the library? They'll likely have your records.

I have no idea which library it was

How many libraries have you ever held a membership card for? It can't possibly be that high a number.

You could improve this question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

For example, were the villains goofy or genuinely evil? Were they older than the hero or the same age? Who was the hero, were they male or female? How were these creatures transformed into monsters (magic/science?). How did the hero defeat them? Did the hero have special powers or a weapon? Did the hero have a sidekick? What was the setting (e.g. fantasy, urban, etc)? Was there explicit sex/violence/gore or was this more of a family-friendly cartoon? Was the cartoon in English?

I was fairly young when I watched it, so I would say that It was fairly family friendly (though that might not be that accurate.) This was more of a fantasy setting, and I believe that the machine they used to turn the pet talking cat into a monster had a glass window and shot the monster out after being injected (might not be completely accurate.) I can't remember if it was a weapon or special powers, but the main character was a boy. It is in English.
